# How to use catchIOError as catch?

Tags: haskell, exception, try-catch

I find the definition in source code.

```
catchIOError :: IO a -> (IOError -> IO a) -> IO a
catchIOError = catch
```

If I want use `catch` instead of `catchIOError` with the same result, how could I do?

```
catchIOError (readFile "test") (\_ -> return "")
```

and use it like:

```
catch (readFile "test") (\_ -> return "")
```

It'll be throw an exception about variable type

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘catch’
prevents the constraint ‘(Exception e0)’ from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘e0’ should be.
```

In other word, is there a way to limit the type without defining a new function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a type annotation:

```
(catch :: IO a -> (IOError -> IO a) -> IO a) (readFile "test") (\_ -> return "")
```